# How to reconnect automatically to restarted mongo db from a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, kubernetes

I created an index for a collection in mongo db using scalegrid. After successfully creating the index, I get "not authorised for query on db" error when logging into the rails app running on kubernetes. When I restart the corresponding pod manually, I am able to login again.
Does anyone know how is it possible to reconnect to the restarted mongo db automatically from the app?

Would updating mongoid or any other gem help here?